# How do I find out the page type of a PageNode? (Composite C1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c1-cms

I want to build an ASP.NET usercontrol that shows a homepage navigation including **only pages of a certain page type** (which I named ContentPage).

In the database table for published pages this information is present for each page (Column `PageTypeID`) but I am unable to find any way to access it via the Composite API from my code.

```
using(var conn = new DataConnection())
{
    var siteMapNav = new SitemapNavigator(conn);
    var pages = siteMapNav.CurrentHomePageNode.GetPageNodes(SitemapScope.DescendantsAndCurrent);
    // what now?
}
```

How can I access the PageType information for a page from C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the data connection to look up the page type on IPage.PageTypeId and then combine the the result from SitemapNavigator:

```
using (var conn = new DataConnection())
{
    Guid pageTypeIdInQuestion = Guid.Empty; // put type id here

    var siteMapNav = new SitemapNavigator(conn);
    var pagesOfDesiredType = conn.Get<IPage>().Where(f => f.PageTypeId == pageTypeIdInQuestion).Select(f => f.Id);
    var pages = siteMapNav.CurrentHomePageNode.GetPageNodes(SitemapScope.DescendantsAndCurrent).Where(f=> pagesOfDesiredType.Contains(f.Id));
}
```

Consider caching the result you get here and flush it with [add/update/delete events](http://api.composite.net/html/AllMembers_T_Composite_Data_DataEvents_1.htm) on IPage and IPageStructure.

Comment: I think this information should be made a part of the PageNode class, there already is a PageType class after all. But your solution works fine for now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pageType = null;
using (var conn = new DataConnection())
{
    var currentPageId = HomePageNode.Id;
    var pageTypeId = conn.Get<IPage>().Where( p => p.Id == currentPageId ).Select( p => p.PageTypeId ).Single();
    pageType = conn.Get<IPageType>().Where(pt => pt.Id == pageTypeId ).Select(pt => pt.Name).Single();
}
```